# Is there a practical use for the Fibonacci sequence or similar fractal/sequence in Electrical Engineering?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, filter, algorithm, ratio

One use of Fractal Engineering is in Fractal Antennas:

> [**An Overview of Fractal Antenna Engineering Research**](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1189650)
>
> Abstract:
>
> Recent efforts by several researchers around the world to combine
> fractal geometry with electromagnetic theory have led to a plethora of
> new and innovative antenna designs. In this report, we provide a
> comprehensive overview of recent developments in the rapidly growing
> field of fractal antenna engineering. Fractal antenna engineering
> research has been primarily focused in two areas: the first deals with
> the analysis and design of fractal antenna elements, and the second
> concerns the application of fractal concepts to the design of antenna
> arrays. Fractals have no characteristic size, and are generally
> composed of many copies of themselves at different scales. These
> unique properties of fractals have been exploited in order to develop
> a new class of antenna-element designs that are multi-band and/or
> compact in size. On the other hand, fractal arrays are a subset of
> thinned arrays, and have been shown to possess several highly
> desirable properties, including multi-band performance, low sidelobe
> levels, and the ability to develop rapid beamforming algorithms based
> on the recursive nature of fractals. Fractal elements and arrays are
> also ideal candidates for use in reconfigurable systems. Finally, we
> provide a brief summary of recent work in the related area of fractal
> frequency-selective surfaces.

And another use of Fractals, this time Engineered as an improved cooling method is this MRI improvement:

> [**Goodbye wires and formers: 3-D additive manufacturing and fractal
> cooling applied to construction of MRI gradient
> coils**](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6152672)
>
> Abstract:
>
> The high pulse frequencies employed in MRI gradient and RF coils call
> for the use of dedicated construction techniques involving special
> wires and cooling systems. These requirements are needed because
> conventional (e.g., solid-core) wires exhibit skin effects at
> frequencies above 10 kHz, which effectively concentrate all the
> current in the periphery of the wire, leading to heating losses due to
> high resistance. To mitigate the resistance problem due to skin-depth,
> many gradient coils (and some RF coils) employ cords of twisted and/or
> woven thin insulated wires (e.g., Litz wires) that force currents to
> traverse the entire wire cross-section. Litz wires are hard to
> configure into the complex designs required for gradient coils, due to
> a minimum turning radius of several millimeters and the asymmetric
> bending forces required for winding the wires onto formers. Another
> challenge in MRI gradient coil manufacturing is the ability to cool RF
> and gradient coils, especially at high pulse rates. Our approach to
> this problem has been to replace traditional wire-coil construction
> methodology with multi-layer additive manufacturing methods, which
> lend themselves to design and manufacture automation. Additive
> manufacturing can enable dramatic (i.e., nearly three-fold)
> improvement in cooling efficiency, through the use of bio-mimetic
> fractal approaches. Building gradient and/or RF coils layer by layer,
> we have added conductive, insulating and cooling elements with
> appropriate interconnects as necessary. A prototype multi-layer Litz
> wire structure was developed, with fractal cooling, which showed
> superior performance (in terms of 80% reduced resistive losses at high
> frequency) to the comparable non-Litz wire configuration.

Fractal cooling patter for MRI circuit:

[image: Fractal cooling patter for MRI circuit]

I would like to know more practical uses for this technology, with a preferred focus on Fibonacci sequence, if possible.

Comment: Googling I find: $$$$ * [The Golden Ratio in an Electrical Network, page 1, J. Wlodarski, 1971](https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/9-2/wlodarski2-a.pdf) $$$$ * [The Golden Ratio in an Electrical Network, page 2, J. Wlodarski, 1971](https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/9-2/wlodarski2-b.pdf) $$$$ * [Modeling of Electrodynamic Systems by the Method of Binary Separation of Additive Parameter in Golden Proportion, Petro Kosobutskyy, 2019](http://ojs.bbwpublisher.com/index.php/JERA/article/download/807/709) $$$$ I'll leave it to you to see how those may help with your curiosity.

Comment: Also, I think this is interesting too. [The golden ratio is more irrational than \$\pi\$!](https://slate.com/technology/2021/06/golden-ratio-phi-irrational-number-ellenberg-shape.html?utm_source=pocket-newtab). But it's not directly related to your question. Still, I hope you find it interesting. And no, I didn't downvote your question. So I'll upvote it to clear the slate.

Comment: I was always curious if superimposing sequence of Phi EM waves would bend them in a such way that would prevent them from becoming TEM waves.

Comment: @jonk -- Actually, that article is perfect. It makes a good argument that the golden ratio is the **most** irrational number. Also, the "Bar Code" method for visualizing the periodicity of an irrational number, when applied to the golden ratio, actually shows **how** it is the most irrational number, and what its strength is. Also, I just realized that the golden ratio squared is equal to its reciprocal plus 2. So the progression of squares looks like (..., 2.Frac, 1.Frac, 0.Frac, ...) where Frac = 0.61803398874989484820458683436564...

Comment: You have a solution looking for a problem, and a weird solution at that. Is there any reason to think it *would* have a practical use?

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD why don't you just write the answer? There are no dibs for discovering something first on Stack Exchange, only for writing it first.

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD Don't forget to avoid jumping to conclusions (not implying). For example you might discover that the 2nd order Bessel transfer function [is related to \$\phi\$](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/371981/95619), but it doesn't mean anything by it -- it's just that it happens to be this way. What I'm trying to say is that you may be thinking along [these lines](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/521118/95619), while the answer may not be what you expect to be.

Comment: (Note: I have deleted some comments which became obsolete, after the OP kindly added the self-answer which was mentioned.)

Comment: @MarkoBuršič -- What do you mean?

Comment: @jonk - Thanks for the article. It was great.

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD With respect to E-seies, did you read my two posts? [1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/381906/38098) and [2](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/440073/38098)?

Comment: @jonk - Very nice, Jonk! Answered some questions for me, and stimulated my thinking too.

Comment: It looks like this one uses fractals to prevent current crowding in a high power MOSFET.
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6229091
This link shows some of the figures/pictures of it:
https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Fractal-structures-for-low-resistance-large-area-Reiner-Waltereit/11188c4a121e93e2a5c0b6f4f6122e364f6e0acb

Comment: I meant a self sustained EM standing waves, or a constrained space between two transceivers where TEM waves are present for power transfer, but in near outer space those waves are cancelled out without radiating power (loss). It has been proved that golden ratio waves are present in the atoms, so it might be a very important discovery to solve the universe puzzle.

Comment: A famous example of fractals, is Benoit Mandlebrot discovering that phone noise and errors occurred fractally, as he was a researcher at AT&T. This work led to all kinds of applications in finance, chaos, and fractals in general. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0EeAclc1OEc

Comment: @pat - That's a great example! It was in a movie on Fractals that I've seen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6229091) uses fractals to prevent current crowding in a high power MOSFET.

In high power transistor design, you want to maximize current by minimizing resistance.

[image: Power transistor fractal evolution]

If you start with a single basic transistor (fist order) with two metalization finger contacts, the wider the transistor is, the lower the transistor active region resistance is. Conversely, your metalization resistance increases because the fingers are getting longer as. You can increase the metal finger thickness to combat this, but then you're simply scaling the entire structure in both the X and Y direction to increase the current. Instead, if we add fingers to the initial two fingers (beginning the fractal), the active area resistance can drop because the transistor channels are now much wider than they are across. The author then extends this into a 2-D pattern for even more efficiency.

The issue is on-resistance would now be dominated by metalization and the current at any specific section of the transistor would become highly non-uniform as shown in their Figure 3.
[image]

In figure 3B, they show a comb-structure (2nd order) and show the highly non-uniform current crowding that occurs. To resolve that, they go further beyond 2nd order and add in metalization that's tapered to help support uniform current transfer between each side of the transistor in Figure 3a.

Comment: I feel like you may have thermal issues in a design like this, but I can't put my finger on *why* I feel that way.

Comment: @Hearth -- Did you read the cited paper. I couldn't because I don't have IEEE access. I [found a related paper, "Design and Characterization of Highly-Efficient GaN-HEMTs for Power Applications"](https://d-nb.info/1137466154/34) which I believe to be very closely related to the one cited by horta (becauses it contains these same diagrams in black and white). If you read the paper, maybe you will either be satisfied, or you can put your finger on what's bothering you. Page 70 begins section "4.4.5 Fractal-Structures for Power Devices". I believe, the Fractal design solves the thermal issues.

Comment: @Hearth Thermal issues are exactly what the fractal design is working to resolve. Current crowding causes thermal hot-spotting. The fractal design allows more even thermal loading across the entire chip. That does mean overall, this chip will be capable of running hotter compared to a non-fractal design.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had stumbled on a way to use Fibonacci to filter the input/output of a power converter, by using LC filters according to a Fibonacci progression of values, but as was pointed out to me, my example did not necessarily prove anything.

Therefore, in place of my original answer, I have improved my answer by merely providing one good example of Fibonacci technology in Electrical Engineering, of which you may not be aware. I hope you like it.

## [**Modified Fibonacci Search Based MPPT Scheme for SPVA Under Partial Shaded Conditions**](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5698353)

> ### Abstract:
>
> **This paper presents the modified Fibonacci search based MPPT scheme for a solar photo voltaic array (SPVA) under partial shaded
> conditions.** The real Fibonacci search based MPPT fails to track the
> global peak (GP) under partial shaded conditions. This paper improves
> the method so that the proposed method tracks GP for all the shaded
> conditions. It is checked for different shading patterns through
> simulation and verified experimentally.

Comment: so the connection is that you could manufacture resistors whose values are the Fibonacci numbers?! That's not even a real connection

Comment: I recognize the same fractal fever that many caught when learning about them, but Fibonacci is not a fractal. It may have some self-similarity in the way it converges, but no more than e.g. exp(x) is self-similar. Interesting thoughts, though, the antenna part more than others, but still have nothing to do with Fibonacci. Which means the question and the answer have very little to do one with another.

Comment: and this is not a practical use

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD The definition of a fractal is not self-similarity alone--otherwise, a plain line would be a fractal.

Comment: I really don't think this is as significant or practical as you think it is. Power supply filtering is a well-studied area, and they almost never use as many stages as you have here.

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD It's really not, and your example with the LC filter is not a great one: you used the same LC values, repeatedly. An `.AC` analysis will show how bad the responses of both ladders are. If your aim is to use an 8th order filter, the best result would be a Bessel, which will give you almost zero overshoot (you're dealing with a power supply, not a signal). I see you have 2 downvotes since my last visit. None mine, but it should make you stop and step back a bit: your premises are wrong (not a fractal) and resembles too much an "I want to believe". Very neutral tone.

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD Using "shooting" and "killing" means a personal take on the matter and, thus, opinionated (the "I want to believe" part), much like your interpretation of the "concerned" part of my nick name (implying I should be concerned about you, or your answer). 3 downvotes (still none mine) should make you consider that it's other people, too, that disagree. Nobody's perfect, and good for you that you're learning through mistakes (IMO the longest lasting lessons), but opinionated means blindness; I would run as fast as I could from that.

Comment: I would like to see a stronger mathematical argument for your noise filtering claim as it currently feels extremely weak. If I took two completely arbitrary LC ladder patterns (linear and fibonacci) then knowing nothing else fibonacci has a 50% chance of being better just for the heck of it. A comparison to the state of the art would be more helpful. Second, the direct Fourier transform doesn't tell us anything useful, because your circuits also attenuate desired signal in the same pattern. If you could demonstrate an actual improvement of the things people actually care about in filters, ...

Comment: ... such as a narrower transition band between a passband and stopband, it may perhaps suggest meaningful results. Furthermore, these ladder circuits are well-understood algebraically, so it is not clear why all I see here is a bunch of statements unrelated to electronics, some beautiful mutant 
cousins of broccoli, and finally a bit of empirical experimentation with one noise source and one LT spice run and not a generalized mathematical statement. A real mathematical treatment may show something interesting, but I suspect that it won't show a real gain compared to state-of-the-art.

Comment: *Now* it's something else. Now, you've focused on finding the links between what you're concerned with (no pun), and the *modified* question. I say modified because you've changed it and, thus, its meaning, which can be considered "sleight of hand" (I'll leave it, though). It's no longer you, blindly gazing at the wonders of fractals, it's about *practical* use of fractals and their applications in real life cases (except the slightly victimized "-5" part; that could be omitted, but I'm probably nitpicking). Only now your answer addresses these concerns. Therefore a deserved +1.